# Primefaces autocomplete inside a custom composite component, behaving as without any suggested result

Tags: jsf, primefaces, custom-component, composite-component

We use a lot of modals in a JSF project, so we made a simple custom component to embed the needed HTML code. Nothing complicated, just a wrapper without any logic:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="modalId" type="java.lang.String" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="styleClass" type="java.lang.String" />
    ...
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.attrs.modalId}" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered #{cc.attrs.styleClass}">
        ...
        <cc:insertChildren />
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In one of this modal, we use a primefaces autocomplete component:

```
<my:modal modalId="myModal">
    ...
    <p:autoComplete value="#{myBean.myValue}" multiple="true" completeMethod="#{myBean.myMethod}"  
        converter="#{myBean.myConverter}" forceSelection="true" unique="true" appendTo="@this" emptyMessage="no result"
        var="example" itemLabel="#{example.name}" itemValue="#{example}" />
    ...
</my:modal>
```

In this state, the dropdown displaying the results behaves as if there were no result at all (the component `emptyMessage` is shown).
Of course, I checked the `completeMethod`, and it is returning results.

If I move the `p:autocomplete` outside the `my:modal` component, or if I replace the modal component by its pure HTML counterpart, everything works fine. So I guess our `my:modal` component is the cause of the fuss.

We're on a JSF 2 and Primefaces 11 project. A lot of other primefaces components (tree, selectBooleanCheckbox, fileUpload, dataTable, ...) are used without any issue in our modals.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Semi off-topic: I'm using an autocomplete component in a custom tag, and it's working for me. I try to avoid composite components as they will get you into trouble pretty fast is my experience.

Comment: Nothing looks out of the ordinary to me here it seems like a relatively simple use case. Are there any errors on the F12 console?

Comment: @Melloware Nope, no client side error. 
In fact, the XHR response providing partial updates returns an empty <ul> for the dropdown results (but I'm 100% sure my bean method is returning a non-empty list).

Comment: This is happening to us now too, Primefaces 11.0.6+, have you been able to find a fix or workaround?

Comment: As the custom component was really lightweight in our case, we chose to remove it and replace it by its HTML content (in the case where we had an autocomplete inside only). So not really a workaround, and absolutely not a fix :-/